# Undefined variable in template

Tags: go, templates

I'm trying to get templates working in Go and I have a question about using local variables.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Go Template Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{$wisdom := "42"}}
        <h1>The meaning of life is {{$wisdom}}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

To run the template, I have a simple `main.go`

```golang
package main

import(
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

// create template container and load all templates into it
var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/**"))
}

func main() {
    // execute to stdout
    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "index.gohtml", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

In this example I'm trying to create a local variable and use it in the template but I get

```bash
> go run main.go                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
panic: template: .index.gohtml.swp:1: undefined variable "$wisdom"                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
goroutine 1 [running]:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
text/template.Must(...)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        /usr/local/go/src/text/template/helper.go:26                                                                                                                                                                                                          
main.init.0()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        <home-path>/dev/go/gosite/main.go:13 +0x65                                                                                                                                                                                                          
exit status 2
```

I originally used the following, passing a string into the `.ExecuteTemplate()` function with the template name and it worked fine so the issue is just that the declaration of the variable is not working

```html
<h1>The meaning of life is {{ . }}</h1>
```

I have also tried using `{{ with $wisdom := "42" }}

## {{$wisdom}}

{{end}} but this also didn't recognise that the variable had been declared

EDIT: see the answer from @mkopriva below

The error is caused by vim invisible files being pulled into the glob but doesn't manifest in a very obvious way. A simple fix would be to make the globbing more specific

```golang
tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.gohtml"))
```

Comment: The code in the question works, see: https://go.dev/play/p/WJ1vibh8Qv9. Note that your error says `.index.gohtml.swp`, that looks like a swap file from vim... The directory you are parsing is either not the one you want, or it contains files you do not expect, or may you expect to have the swap file there, but then you should know that files with the same name (sans extension) will override each other, only the last one will be kept.

Comment: that was absolutely it. I fixed it by making the template glob more specific - `tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.gohtml"))`. Thanks so much - please feel free to add an answer and i'll mark this as answered

Comment: I'm undeleting this to show what a stupid error it is and warn other golang vim users